# Проблема с predict_proba при выполнении в процессе

Tags: python, python-2.x, multiprocessing, xgboost, pickle

История состоит в следующем. Если я пытаюсь выполнить метод `predict_proba` внутри процесса, то выполнение программы блокируется.

Если вынести метод `predict_proba` из процесса, то всё будет отлично и всё заработает.

Более того, если не производить обучение модели и закомментить `process`, то всё тоже будет работать.

Проблема, судя по всему, именно с `XGBoost`, поскольку, `LinearRegression` из *sklearn* работает отлично.

В чём беда?

К сожалению, использовать *xgboost saver* не могу, поскольку используются *sklearn-pipelines* (в примере они не приведены). Так что это решение отпадает. Других сериализаторов я не знаю.

**Минимальный работающий пример**:

```
import cPickle as pkl
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import multiprocessing


size = 2
features = 2


def tmp():
    with open('../data/models/union_XGB_base.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        md = pkl.load(f)
    data = np.random.rand(size, features)
    print('Start')
    print md.predict_proba(data)
    print('Finish')


def process():
    md = XGBClassifier(max_depth=1, n_estimators=1)
    md.fit(np.random.rand(size, features), np.uint(np.random.rand(size) > 0.5))
    with open('../data/models/union_XGB_base.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pkl.dump(md, f)


def main():

    process()
    multiprocessing.Process(target=tmp).start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, о проблеме [известно](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2163). Корни идут в глубины архитектуры юникса. В частности:

> If you are using multiprocess's forking, that issue might be related to the known gcc problem of OpenMP within unix forks

http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#OpenmpAndFork
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58378

Замечу, на *python3.5* тоже не работает из коробки. На *python3.6* запускается.

Для того, чтобы `xgboost` заработал на версии *3.5*, необходимо:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; make -j4
cd python-package
python setup.py install
```